# Why is the state not being properly updated in this React Native component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, settimeout, use-effect

I have a React Native component being used on multiple screens in which I use a reoccurring `setTimeout` function to animate a carousel of images. The carousel works great, but I want to properly clear out the timer when the screen is navigated away from in the callback function returned from the `useEffect` hook. (If I don't clear out the timer, then I get a nasty error, and I know I'm supposed to clean up timers anyway.)

For whatever reason though, the state variable I'm trying to set the `setTimeout` returned timeout ID to seems to be set to `null` in the callback returned from `useEffect`.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
const Carousel = () => {
    const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState(null);

    const startCarouselCycle = () => {
        const newTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            // Code here that calls scrollToIndex for the FlatList.
        }, 5000);

        setTimeoutId(newTimeoutId);
    };

    const startNextCarouselCycle = () => {
        // Other code here.
        startCarouselCycle();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        startCarouselCycle();

        return () => {
            // This is called when the screen with the carousel
            // is navigated away from, but timeoutId is null.
            // Why?!
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <FlatList
            // Non-essential code removed.
            horizontal={true}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            onMomentumScrollEnd={startNextCarouselCycle}
        />
    );
};

export default Carousel;
```

Does anyone have any idea why the state would not be properly updating for use in the returned `useEffect` callback? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the dependency array from your `useEffect` hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    startCarouselCycle();

    return () => {
        // This is called when the screen with the carousel
        // is navigated away from, but timeoutId is null.
        // Why?!
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
});
```

This is because your effect is triggered once when the component mounts and it only gets the initial value of your `timeoutId`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Al. That helps a lot. If I remove the `[]` argument from `useEffect` though, isn't that going to cause the component to be continuously refreshed? Also, even if I do keep the `[]` argument, I'm still confused about why that locks the state into the first value. The state is set up outside of the `useEffect` function, so I would think that `useEffect` would just inherit whatever the current value of `timeoutId` is when the callback is returned from the `useEffect` hook. That not the case? Very confusing. Anyway, thank you. And additional insight you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing `timeoutId` in state? Try return the value from your function like this https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-wave-5zyn2

Comment: Well, being a carousel, every time the `setTimeout` function gets called, it rotates one image, and then calls the `startNextCarouselCycle` function to start a new `setTimeout`. As such, I need to always know what the latest timer ID is, and then use that to clear the timer when the screen with the component is navigated away from in `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've seen I don't think it's necessary to store your timeout ID in state. Try this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';

const Carousel = () => {
    let _timeoutId = null

    const startCarouselCycle = () => {
        const newTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            // Code here that calls scrollToIndex for the FlatList.
        }, 5000);

        _timeoutId = newTimeoutId;
    };

    const startNextCarouselCycle = () => {
        // Other code here.
        startCarouselCycle();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        startCarouselCycle();

        return () => {
            // This is called when the screen with the carousel
            // is navigated away from, but timeoutId is null.
            // Why?!
            clearTimeout(_timeoutId);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <FlatList
            // Non-essential code removed.
            horizontal={true}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            onMomentumScrollEnd={startNextCarouselCycle} />
    );
};

export default Carousel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for your answers and feedback. I tried implementing what everyone recommended, but to no avail. Luckily, they started me off on the right path, and for all I know, maybe there was something else in my component that I didn't mention in my question that was causing things to be more complex.

All the same, after banging my head against a wall for days, I was able to resolve this problem with the following:

```
let timeoutId;

const Carousel = () => {
    const startCarouselCycle = () => {
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            // Code here that calls scrollToIndex for the FlatList.
        }, 5000);
    };

    const startNextCarouselCycle = () => {
        // Other code here.
        startCarouselCycle();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        startCarouselCycle();

        return () => {
            if (timeoutId) {
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            }
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <FlatList
            // Non-essential code removed.
            horizontal={true}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            onMomentumScrollEnd={startNextCarouselCycle}
        />
    );
};

export default Carousel;
```

The main thing I changed was moving the `timeoutId` variable to **outside** the component render function. The render function is getting continuously called, which was causing the `timeoutId` to not properly update (no clue why; some closure issue?!).

All the same, moving the variable outside the `Carousel` function did the trick.